# How to generate monthly time series data with NA values for running examples?

Tags: r, time-series

I apologize in advance for the simplicity of this question.

How can I generate a monthly time series data set using something like set seed? I have a question about results from two packages but need to create a sample data set to show as an example. My data set needs to have some NA values within in it.

Regards,

Simon

Comment: What do you mean by time-series data? A `ts` object specifically? Or `xts` / `zoo`? Or just a series of values? You can just take a random sample of values like: `ts(sample(c(1:3,NA)), freq=12)` - is that kind of what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a random list of 1000 dates +- 5 years from today with some missing data using the `simstudy` package (please provide sample data and expected output for a more specific answer):

```
library(simstudy)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1724)

# define data
def <- defData(varname = "tmp", dist = "uniform", formula = "0;1") # sumstudy seems to crash when adding missing data with only 1 column
def <- defData(def, varname = "date", dist = "uniform", formula = "-5;5") # +- 5 years
df_full <- genData(1000, def)

##### missing data ----
defM <- defMiss(varname = "date", formula = 0.1, logit.link = F)
df_missing <- genMiss(df_full, defM, idvars = "id")

# Create data with missing values
df <- genObs(df_full, df_missing, idvars = "id")

df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(-tmp) %>%
  mutate(date = ymd(floor_date(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()) + date * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, unit = "day")), # +- 5 years from today
         month = format(date, "%Y-%m"))

# A tibble: 1,000 x 3
      id date       month  
   <int> <date>     <chr>  
 1     1 NA         NA     
 2     2 2021-09-12 2021-09
 3     3 2023-11-08 2023-11
 4     4 2015-03-02 2015-03
 5     5 2021-08-12 2021-08
 6     6 2021-10-20 2021-10
 7     7 2017-05-17 2017-05
 8     8 2019-04-12 2019-04
 9     9 NA         NA     
10    10 NA         NA     
# ... with 990 more rows
```